# Issue installing Kali Linux on VM Man-db.amd

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kali-linux

I've been trying to install kali on virtual box, but I consistently get stuck on processing triggers for mandb, I've tried it several times and even left it overnight twice, but it doesn't work so I'm assuming that it's probably corrupt. Any help?

The exact issue in case it was unclear is that the installation freezes once it tries to install processing triggers for man-db.amd

Comment: Did you set BIOS on the host machine for Hardware Virtualization and Vt-d (enabled)?  Your Kali machine is almost for sure 64-bit.  (Posted from my Kali VM machine)

Comment: Don't install it. It's not intended to be installed. If you need a security testing Linux, boot it from ISO. If you want to learn Linux, pick something non-specialized like Ubuntu or Debian.

Comment: I have enabled all options in my bios. I am trying to use Kali for ethical hacking and I am trying to install from ISO, I don't know how to remove it from the install however.